# Populate cell in csv file with data from cell above

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a CSV file which contains order information as follows:

```
OrderNo     SKU     PaidDate     BuyerName         Buyer Address     Buyer Phone No.
NG0001      ABC1    20150727     MR A. SMITH       1 HIGH STREET     01234 567890
NG0001      DEF2              
NG0001      XYZ3      
NG0002      ABC1    20150728     MRS B. JONES      100 LONDON ROAD   07766 554433
NG0002      DEF2
```

I need to populate the columns that are empty with the data in the columns above (based on the order number), so it becomes:

```
OrderNo     SKU     PaidDate     BuyerName         Buyer Address     Buyer Phone No.
NG0001      ABC1    20150727     MR A. SMITH       1 HIGH STREET     01234 567890
NG0001      DEF2    20150727     MR A. SMITH       1 HIGH STREET     01234 567890
NG0001      XYZ3    20150727     MR A. SMITH       1 HIGH STREET     01234 567890
NG0002      ABC1    20150728     MRS B. JONES      100 LONDON ROAD   07766 554433
NG0002      DEF2    20150728     MRS B. JONES      100 LONDON ROAD   07766 554433
```

I can do this in an Excel formula by comparing the order numbers between rows and referencing the above cell if they are the same, but cannot work out how to do the same in Powershell - is there a way of doing something similar to this:

```
ForEach-Object {if ($_.OrderNo=$_.OrderNo in row above) $_.PaidDate=$_.PaidDate in row above;}
```

Or am I going about this completely the wrong way and need to rethink in a less Excel-ly, more Powershell-y way?

Comment: Will the first row of an order number _always_ be populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$Data = Import-Csv "C:\temp\Testing.csv"

$i = 0
foreach ($Entry in $Data) {
    if ($Entry.PaidDate -eq "" -and $i -ne 0 -and $Data[$i].OrderNo -eq $Data[$i - 1].OrderNo) {
        $Data[$i].PaidDate = $Data[$i - 1].PaidDate
        $Data[$i].BuyerName = $Data[$i - 1].BuyerName
        $Data[$i].'Buyer Address' = $Data[$i - 1].'Buyer Address'
        $Data[$i].Buyer = $Data[$i - 1].Buyer
        $Data[$i].'Phone No.' = $Data[$i - 1].'Phone No.'
    }

    $i++
}

$Data
```

What that does is test for an empty `PaidDate`, and if that's the case (as well as if it isn't the first row, and likewise if it's the same `OrderNo` as the previous entry) then it'll set the properties equal to the one above it.

After this runs, `$Data` contains the populated data, and you can handle from there (i.e. output it back to the CSV file, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of this is that basically the `SKU` is the only thing that is changing. Read the file as a CSV into PowerShell and then calculate the master rows that we will be using as templates. As we look at each row then individually match its content to its associated master row.

```psh
# All of the data of the CSV file
$allData = Import-Csv "c:\temp\test.csv"

# Rows with complete data to be used as templates.
$masterRows = $allData | Where-Object{$_."PaidDate" -and $_.BuyerName -and $_."Buyer Address" -and $_."Buyer Phone No."}

$allData | ForEach-Object{
    $singleRow = $_
    $newRow = $masterRows | Where-Object{$singleRow.OrderNo -eq $_.OrderNo} 
    $newRow.SKU = $singleRow.SKU
    $newRow
} | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation "C:\temp\output.csv"
```

As we navigate each row we just match up that rows `orderno` with its matching equivalent in the `$masterRows`. Then take a copy of that `$masterRow` and update its SKU before sending it down the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

First i setup a here string containing your csv data and export it to a file.

```
$csv1 = @"
OrderNo,SKU,PaidDate,BuyerName,Buyer Address,Buyer Phone No.
NG0001,ABC1,20150727,MR A. SMITH,1 HIGH STREET,01234 567890
NG0001,DEF2
NG0001,XYZ3
NG0002,ABC1,20150728,MRS B. JONES,100 LONDON ROAD,07766 554433
NG0002,DEF2
"@

$csv1 | Set-Content csvfile1.csv
```

Then import the file again

```
$actual = Import-Csv csvfile1.csv
```

Use powershell Group-Object CmdLet to Group by OrderNo

```
$grouper = $actual | Group-Object -Property OrderNo

foreach ($group in $grouper)
{
    # Save properties from first item in group
    $paiddate = $group.Group[0].PaidDate
    $buyername = $group.Group[0].BuyerName
    $buyerAddress = $group.Group[0].'Buyer Address'
    $buyerPhoneNo = $group.Group[0].'Buyer Phone No.'
    # Copy properties if empty
    foreach ($item in $group.Group)
    {
        if ($item.PaidDate -eq $null){$item.PaidDate = $paiddate}
        if ($item.BuyerName -eq $null){$item.BuyerName = $buyername}
        if ($item."Buyer Address" -eq $null){$item."Buyer Address" = $buyerAddress}
        if ($item."Buyer Phone No." -eq $null){$item."Buyer Phone No." = $buyerPhoneNo}
    }
}
```

Show the result

```
$actual


OrderNo         : NG0001
SKU             : ABC1
PaidDate        : 20150727
BuyerName       : MR A. SMITH
Buyer Address   : 1 HIGH STREET
Buyer Phone No. : 01234 567890

OrderNo         : NG0001
SKU             : DEF2
PaidDate        : 20150727
BuyerName       : MR A. SMITH
Buyer Address   : 1 HIGH STREET
Buyer Phone No. : 01234 567890

OrderNo         : NG0001
SKU             : XYZ3
PaidDate        : 20150727
BuyerName       : MR A. SMITH
Buyer Address   : 1 HIGH STREET
Buyer Phone No. : 01234 567890

OrderNo         : NG0002
SKU             : ABC1
PaidDate        : 20150728
BuyerName       : MRS B. JONES
Buyer Address   : 100 LONDON ROAD
Buyer Phone No. : 07766 554433

OrderNo         : NG0002
SKU             : DEF2
PaidDate        : 20150728
BuyerName       : MRS B. JONES
Buyer Address   : 100 LONDON ROAD
Buyer Phone No. : 07766 554433
```

Hope it will work out for you.